# why is my "option+e" hotkey displaying a different menu in blender 3.3?

Tags: modeling

so i'm a mac blender user, and i'm having issues with option+e ("alt+e") hotkey. the first image is what i should be seeing, and the second is what i actually see. this is in faces editing mode, and i'm using blender 3.3.1. how do i get these options now?

sorry if i should be adding more info, i'm semi-new

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure at least one face is selected before you press the key ?

Comment: i am pretty sure thibsert is right. Yes, you are in face selection mode, but you didn't select face. If this doesn't help you, pls make a short video what you are doing and so we can help you furthermore.

Comment: i've figured out the issue! technically the face was selected but it was having some weird clipping issues and had a bit of a freak-out lol, i managed to fix everything just fine though. thanks! and sorry for the super simple easy-fix problem lol